# How to hide html on form from directive template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a basic Angular question.

I have a Directive Template that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <form name="newPhotosForm" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-disabled="appStatus.busy || fileManagerStatus.uploading">
        <div class="" ng-hide="hasFiles">
            <label for="newPhotos">Select and upload attachment</label>
            <input type="file" id="newPhotos" class="uploadFile" accept="image/*" files="files" has-files="hasFiles" multiple>
        </div>
        <div class="" ng-show="hasFiles && !fileManagerStatus.uploading">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><strong>files:</strong></li>
                <li ng-repeat="file in files"> {{file.name}}</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-upload="upload(files)" ng-click="upload(files);reset()" file-on-change="fileChange($files)" value="upload">
            <input class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" value="cancel" />
        </div>
        <div class="" ng-show="fileManagerStatus.uploading">
            <p class="help-block">uploading</p>
        </div>
        <br />



        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="file in imageFiles">
                <a ng-href="" ng-click='handleGetAttachmentSuccess(file.name)' ng-model="item.imageFile">{{file.ImageName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </form>
</div>
```

It's basically used to upload files.  And I have a regular form (i.e. HTML) that displays a list of file attachments when the form loads.  I'm trying to synchronize the two to make them work together.  Basically what i want to happen is this:

When the form loads I want the template to display the file select dialog and I want my regular form to display a list of files attached to the item displayed (if any).   When I select a file using the Directive Template I want the list of files displayed in my regular form hidden.  The problem is I'm not sure how to communicate between my Directive Template and regular form.  Basically I just want to hide my regular form and let the Template display the file list when I'm uploading files.

Here's the file upload function which is in an Angular Factory:

```
function upload(files) {
            //ToDo Check that file extension exists here

            service.status.uploading = true;
            appInfo.setInfo({ busy: true, message: "uploading files" });

            var formData = new FormData();

            angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
                formData.append(file.name, file);
            });


            return fileManagerClient.save(formData)
                                        .$promise
                                        .then(function (result) {
                                            if (result && result.files) {
                                                result.files.forEach(function (file) {
                                                    if (!fileExists(file.name)) {
                                                        service.files.push(file);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }

                                            appInfo.setInfo({ message: "files uploaded successfully" });

                                            return result.$promise;
                                        },
                                        function (result) {
                                            appInfo.setInfo({ message: "something went wrong: " + result.data.message });
                                            return $q.reject(result);
                                        })
                                        ['finally'](
                                        function () {
                                            appInfo.setInfo({ busy: false });
                                            service.status.uploading = false;
                                        });
        }
```

Here's the relevant source code for the regular form page:

```
 <ul ng-show="showList">
                    <li ng-repeat="attachment in item.Images">
                        <a ng-href="" ng-click='viewAttachment($event, attachment, $index)' ng-model="item.imageFile">{{attachment.ImageName}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Also, there may be another way to do this so any/all help/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Think of a directive as the same as another html element except that you are defining it's structure and how it functions. So when you use that directive in your html, that directive needs to have functions of its own that get triggered by your outside events. Take a look at $broadcast, $emit and $on. It would be useful to post the hosting pages full html as well so that we can help.

Comment: Thank you haakon319.  Added the relevant source code for the "regular" form page.